# Import of SQL Dump

Tags: bash, shell, automation, scripting, sh

From the below extract of data I am trying to view out only the items in bold, is there a way to do this? The specific section of the file of this is important which is why the 'into .db. values' is important - also assume I do NOT know the actual value of these

```
 grep "INTO .db. VALUES" ./anikokiss_mysql4.sql
```

INSERT INTO `db` VALUES ('localhost','**blog**','yscr_bbYcqN','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N'),('localhost','**blog1**','yscr_bbS4kf','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N'),('localhost','**blog**','yscr_bbhrSZ','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N'),('localhost','**blog**','yscr_bbBl0C','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N'),('localhost','**blog**','yscr_bbrsKX','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N');

Result of

```
cut -d',' -f2 <(awk '/.*INTO .?db.? VALUES.*/,/.*;/{if (NR > 2) nr[NR]}; NR in nr' ./anikokiss_mysql4.sql)
```

Is

```
'blog'
```

As such it appears to only pick the first batch of command seperated values and ignore those after

Similarly with grep command

```
grep "INTO .db. VALUES" ./anikokiss_mysql4.sql | cut -d "'" -f4
```

We get the result

```
blog
```

When I was updating DB names

```
find . -name '*.sql' -exec sed -i "s/\\(CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\\)/\\1${cpuser}_/" {} +
```

Current output

```
[root@uk01 public_html]# grep -Pzo '(?s)INTO .?db.? VALUES[^(]\K[^;]*' aniko.sql | grep -Pao '\(([^,]*,){2}\K[^,]*' | sed -e 's/^/test_/'
test_'yscr_bbYcqN'
test_'yscr_bbS4kf'
test_'yscr_bbhrSZ'
test_'yscr_bbBl0C'
test_'yscr_bbrsKX'
```

Comment: Before trying to answer your question, I would like to check that I understand you well. I think that you only want to see the second field that is selected. Can you edit your question and show what you want to see (is this only `blog`, `blog1`,`blog`,`blog`,`blog`)? When you also show what you tried (something like `| cut -d "'" -f4`) and what is wrong with that, I even get a better understanding how I can help you.

Comment: Hi Waiter, you’re right - only the second field in each line.

Comment: You can edit your question, showing the resilt I gave and show what command you tries to get that result.

Comment: Do you want to get everything after `INTO .db. Values`? Or just everything in that section?

Comment: Now added the relevant code to the main question

Comment: @MaximilianBallard just in that section, not everything after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `grep` to achieve what you want:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)INTO .?db.? VALUES[^(]\K[^;]*' ./anikokiss_mysql4.sql | grep -Pao '\([^,]*,\K[^,]*'
```

First I use `grep` to get everything after `INTO db VALUES`. Then, pass the output of that to another instance of `grep` which cuts it after the first `,`.

To change what column to get you can just keep repeating the look behind in the last grep `{N}`:

```
# This gets first column
grep -Pzo '(?s)INTO .?db.? VALUES[^(]\K[^;]*' file | grep -Pao '\(([^,]*,){0}\K[^,]*'
# This gets fourth column
grep -Pzo '(?s)INTO .?db.? VALUES[^(]\K[^;]*' file | grep -Pao '\(([^,]*,){3}\K[^,]*'
```

Will get the fourth column,

Comment: Bingo! Perfect, if I then wanted to grep for arguments sake the 2nd and 3rd values, how would I do that? Just so I understand how to make the relevant changes

Comment: @lukederbyshire Updated my answer. Basically just keep repeating the look behind in the last grep, its zero indexed so 0 would be 1st column and so on.

Comment: Is there a way to combine this with a sed command? Like I did to earlier in my code with DB names (see what I did with those - it's the exact same format that I did there with this, just added the variable {$cpuser}_ to the start of each find (added what I used into the main question)

Comment: @lukederbyshire yeah you would just pipe that sed output into the like `find -exec sed \; | grep `. or append the output to file then use that file as the input grep. Something like `-exec sed "something" >> file.sql \;` and then just use that file with grep.

Comment: I tried the below but it puts the prefix before the opening ' of the output, where am I Going wrong grep -Pzo '(?s)INTO .?db.? VALUES[^(]\K[^;]*' aniko.sql | grep -Pao '\(([^,]*,){2}\K[^,]*' | sed -e 's/^/test/'

Comment: @lukederbyshire Do you want to run the sed command before the grep command?

Comment: No because I need to get the results of your grep first to know what I need to do amend basically adding a prefix (but inside the first ') - so for arguments sake if your output is 'test' I'd want to pipe to sed to change it to 'PREFIX_test'. I've added where I've got so far to the main post for you to see, I need the prefix inside the first '